# Square roots + - sign deciding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it correct to say that for solving x^2 = 49 , we can square root both sides we would get |x| = 7 so that means x can be either 7 or -7 ? If yes in the situation like finding square root of some numbers let say 100 taking square root of that will give +10 or -10 too ? +10 is only true because the (square root function ) gives always positive answer ? But when we are considering a variable x square root it can be both + - values because we dont know where √x might lie ?

Comment: What you wrote is correct.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: This may be helpful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root.

Comment: More usual is to say that for $y \geq 0, ~x^2 = y \iff x = \pm \sqrt{y}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is mostly correct, if a little confusingly written. The situation is as such:

- For every positive real number $a$, the equation $x^2=a$ has precisely two solutions.
- The two solutions of the equation $x^2=a$ have the same absolute value, but one of the solutions is positive and the other is negative. For example, the equation $x^2=100$ has two solutions, one solution is $10$, the other is $-10$.
- The square root is a **function** that maps non-negative real numbers to non-negative real numbers. It is defined such that $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the non-negative solution to the equation $x^2=a$. Because of the properties above, this is a well defined function.

---

Taking all that I wrote into consideration, there are a few things you wrote that are not true. In particular:

> In the situation like finding square root of some numbers let say 100 taking square root of that will give +10 or -10 too ?

No. The square root of $100$ is $10$. The number $-10$ is **not** equal to the number $\sqrt{100}$. **However**, both the number $10$ and the number $-10$ are solutions to the equation $x^2=100$.

> But when we are considering a variable x square root it can be both + - values because we dont know where √x might lie

No. We **know** the square root of a positive number is always positive. However, when solving an equation like $x^2=a$, then, if all we know about $x$ is that it solves that equation, then we know that $x$ is equal to either $\sqrt{a}$ or it is equal to $-\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: If we say that $7i$ has five fifth roots, do we also say that $7$ has five fifth roots?

Comment: @ryang In $\mathbb C$, every nonzero number has five fifth roots, and $n$ $n$-th roots in general. That is, for every $w\neq 0$, the equation $z^n=w$ has $n$ distinct solutions.

Comment: Thanks, @5xum. So, just as $7$ has five fifth roots, it has two second roots, that is, it technically has two *square* roots (but one principal square root), [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409033/why-imaginary-numbers-exist-when-we-have-negative-square-root#comment9222618_4409033)?

Comment: @ryang $7$ has two square roots in $\mathbb C$. But in $\mathbb R$, the term root is not used in the same way as in $\mathbb C$. In $\mathbb R$, "the square root of a number", that is, the number defined as $\sqrt{a}$, is a single well defined number. I will admit there is some terminological confusion, as the terms overlap somewhat, but not perfectly. This is exactly why I don't like talking about "roots of a number", but rather about roots of an *equation*. But anyway, this is all veering off topic.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!  My choice has been to distinguish $a^{\frac1n}$ in $\mathbb C$ (multi-valued) from $a^{\frac1n}$ in $\mathbb R$ (single-valued), and to refrain from using the notation $\sqrt a$ unless $a\geq0.$ I *do* frequently verbalise $\sqrt a$ as simply as "square root of $a$", but merely as a verbal shorthand for "*principal* square root of $a$". I shall continue to think of $7$ as technically having two square roots even in $\mathbb R.$ -)

Comment: @ryang Mater of personal preference probably, but to me, the term "root" in $\mathbb R$ is a different term than the term "root" in $\mathbb C$. They are tightly related, of course (the root in $\mathbb R$ is equal to the principal root on $\mathbb C$, as you say), but I try to keep them stored in my brain as two separate concepts.

Comment: It is indeed a matter of chosen framing. Mine requires me to note that *even* in $\mathbb R,$ “the $n$th root” is merely verbal shorthand for “the principal $n$th root”, while yours requires you to note that *unlike* in $\mathbb C,\:7$ has exactly one fifth root. Thanks for clarifying!